# xampp запуск django сервера

Tags: django, apache, сервер, xampp, mod-wsgi

Хочу запустить django сервер. Использую x64 windows 10. Поставил xampp, хотел установить mod_wsgi, открыл файл 
mod_wsgi-4.6.4+ap24vc9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl,
скаченный с [сайт](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi).
Копировал mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.pyd в apache/modules, переименовал в mod_wsgi.so.
Прописал в httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
...
<IfModule wsgi_module>
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:\xampp\htdocs\hello_world\hello_world\wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath C:\xampp\htdocs\hello_world\
    <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\hello_world\>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

При попытке запустить из xampp, говорит 
"Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly."
Изменение настроек портов не помогло. Отрыл в cmd C:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe, мне выдало

```
"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 186 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: %1 \xed\xe5 \xff\xe2\xeb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec Win32."
```

Эта строка из файла

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

При такой же установке 32х битной версии mod_wgsi выдает

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 186 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.
```

Вроде все написал, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: «переименовал в mod_wsgi.so» — зачем?

Comment: А как ещё можно заставить апачи работать с ним?

Comment: Установить whl-файл по-нормальному через pip, например?

Comment: `pip install mod_wsgi-4.6.4+ap24vc9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` находясь в одной папке с этим файлом, очевидно. А потом, если установка пройдёт успешно, уже и mod_wsgi.so должен где-нибудь появиться

Comment: Если написать просто pip intall, то выдает https://docs.google.com/document/d/1il_18McEPjHVJL5WmdLBYX55qNfCWwPTWFxucgBIWn4/edit?usp=sharing , если писать pip install mod_wsgi  MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR C:\xampp\apache, то выдает Directory 'C:\\xampp\\apache' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.

Comment: Ещё раз: вот так → `pip install mod_wsgi-4.6.4+ap24vc9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`

Comment: Между прочим, вы возможно ещё и не ту версию скачали. Если у вас 64-битная винда и 64-битный апач, то и mod_wsgi тоже должен быть 64-битный

Comment: И версию питона обязательно проверьте, чтобы она совпадала с версией, под которую сделан скачанный вами mod_wsgi (2.7)

Comment: ОООООО, я 4 часа пытался совместить второй и третий питон. Оно заработало, когда я скачал mod_wsgi‑4.6.4+ap24vc14‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl. Большое спасибо за помощь